# Left join on unrelated tables in Query DSL and JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl

I have two unrelated tables, each one with field email. I need a query which introduces column taken from second table if emails match or will be null if no match is found. In SQL this is easy:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.email, tableB.name
 FROM tableA
 LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.email=tableB.email
 ORDER BY tableB.name
```

Unfortunately JPA doesn't allow joins over unrelated entities so I converted it to:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.email,
       (SELECT tableB.name FROM tableB WHERE tableB.email=tableA.email) AS aname
  FROM tableA
  ORDER BY aname
```

Now, it works as JPA query but we are using Query DSL so off we go to converting it:

```
JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
List<Dto> items=query.from(qTableA)
  .list(new QDto(qTableA.id, qTableA.email,
                 new JPASubQuery().from(qTableB)
                  .where(qTableB.email.eq(qTableA.email)).unique(qTableB.name)))
```

It works but now I have no idea how to implement sorting and filtering by field introduced by subquery.

`Dto` is a POJO used to collect results, `QDto` is a class autogenerated from `Dto`.

Question is: how to join two unrelated tables using Query DSL and JPA and avoiding native SQL? Is it possible? Sorting and filtering on fields from tableA and tableB.name is a requirement.

Comment: Here is link for performing join using JPA http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: Just make sure you use tableB inside tableA with email as join point. you don't have those be inter-related with each other in mysql or database.

Comment: @javadev unfortunately I cannot use joins because JPA is not supporting joins over unrelated entities. What is working in SQL doesn't work in JPA and subsequently Query DSL.

Comment: I think @javadev is suggesting to Map relationship from A<>B: doesn't have to be exposed to the outside world but might simplify things?

Comment: @AlanHay Yes I am suggesting to map entities in java classes but don't need to map them in mysql database.

Comment: @javadev Oh, I didn't understand that. How can I link those classes in JPA only? I suppose the email field should be the link, right?

Comment: @pacinpm yes email field should be the link.

Answer (score 0):

Join on unrelated entities is not covered by latest JPA spec (2.1)

However Hibernate 5.1.0+ and EclipseLink 2.4.0+ support ad hoc joins. http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/03/join-unrelated-entities-in-jpa.html